# Network performance issues in AWS RDS with bulk insert

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

I need to load a large csv file (16 GB in total) into AWS RDS (MariaDB).

I tried to load via LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

It was running very fast in my local environment, but very slow in RDS (about 0.01 MB/Sec).

Of course, I loaded the 16GB file separately, and the connection to the DB was also released normally in the code I wrote, and there was nothing unusual about checking the current process with show processlist.

I would like to know what to check and fix in this situation to improve network performance.

Thank You.

Comment: What is the instance type of your RDS database? If it's a burstable instance, do you have CPU credits? What is the bandwidth between your PC and the RDS instance? Are there any indexes or constraints on the table that you're loading into?

Comment: It has to shovel 16GB across the network.

Comment: We using db.m5.large. So, bandwith is maximum 4750 Mbps and network performance is maximum 10 Gbps. But, currently network receive throughput approximately 0.01MB/Sec. Sometimes the throughput goes up, but it's only temporary and goes right down. Table just has 2 columns. I tried it on EC2 in the same VPC as RDS, but the performance was the same.